# How many points is a UIImage taken from an iPhone 5/5s camera

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How many points is the width and height of a UIImage that gets created from the UIImagePickerController when it takes a picture?

I have an iPhone 4s and can see that it is 2448 by 3264 but is it the same for iPhone 5/5s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the same size as the iPhone 5 and 5S.

You can check a `UIImage`'s size by the following code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSLog(@"Image width: %f",image.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Image height: %f",image.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I was checking the 4s's size. Thanks.